# How to write OR function in Grafana with Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have been trying to figure out how to write OR function with prometheus inside Grafana. I ahve been reading [Operators Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/) and so far I was only able to get a positive sum where the negative doesn't seem to work.

[image: Grafana]

The positive scenario is that when the response is either 200 or 404 `sum(scraper_request_count_total{http_status=~"200|404"})` then its a successful request and everything else is failed requests. I thought it would work by doing `sum(scraper_request_count_total{http_status!="200|404"})` but it doesn't, that gives me an ouput that its failed request even though the request is returning 200.

My question is, how can I write a "negative" OR function where I want the response to NOT be either 200 OR 404, meaning all other response status code is counted as false if not 200/404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [per docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors), with `!~` you can select labels that *do not* regex-match the provided string, that is, the following should work for you:

```
sum(scraper_request_count_total{http_status!~"200|404"}
```

Comment: Oh, I must have missed that small text in there. You are correct. Tested and it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped and really it just means we need to improve the docs ;)

Comment: Guess a example of !~ wouldn't hurt maybe :D